# Getting FieldError in modelformset factory in django view.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.9

I am getting FieldError as :

> Unknown field(s) (notedate) specified for AssistantNotes

When i call the page. It throws this error. I am using Django 1.9.5 and python 2.7.
I have notedate field in the AssistantNotes table in my db. If i delete "notedate" from modelformset_factory row in my view, it works. I couldnt solve why it is not showing notedate although it is in DB and in model. And generating error. The field is already in the model.

My view is :

```
def edit_assistant_notes(request):
    isassistantsuperadmin = getUserPermissions(request) #Yes if 1, no if 0
    list = getUserType(request)
    userisassistant = list[2]
    if userisassistant == "YES" or isassistantsuperadmin ==1: 
        list = getUserType(request)
        type = list[0]
        usertype = list[1] #"Nöbetçi Muavin":1 , "Yetkili":2
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if AssistantNotes.objects.filter(notedate=nicosia_date(datetime.today()).date()).count() == 0:
                AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('time', 'notedate', 'categories', 'type', 'dailynote',))
            else:
                AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('time', 'notedate', 'categories', 'type', 'dailynote',), can_delete=True)
            if usertype == 1:
                formset = AssistantNotesFormsetFactory(queryset=AssistantNotes.objects.filter(notedate=nicosia_date(datetime.today()).date(), type=type))
            elif usertype == 2:
                formset = AssistantNotesFormsetFactory(queryset=AssistantNotes.objects.all().order_by("notedate", "time"))
            helper = TableInlineHelper()
            return render(request, 'edit-assistant-notes.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper})
```

My model is :

```
    class AssistantNotes(BaseModel):
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, default="GENERAL", max_length=100, verbose_name=_("CAT"))
    time = models.CharField(choices=TIME, default="-------------", max_length=20, verbose_name=_("Time"))
    dailynote = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Add Note"))
    writer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Adder"))
    notedate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("Date"))
    type = models.CharField(choices=SCHOOLTYPE, default="---", max_length=100, verbose_name=_("SchoolType"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s / %s" % (self.dailynote, self.categories)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dailynote']
```

Comment: Why do you need to include in the form when it has `auto_now_add=True`?

Comment: The viewer of the page should see the date of the note entered. There will be several notes with different dates. User will differentiate which note to edit by date. Will not change the date. Just show.

Comment: >DateField.auto_now_add¶
>As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False
>Field.editable¶
If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

Comment: You might need to remove auto_now_add from it and then set `readonly` attribute of the field to True.

Comment: So should i add dates manually in the code in the view ? Isn't it possible to show editable=False fields in the form as readonly ?

Comment: Or can i make the field editable ?

Comment: How can i  force this field to be editable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182074/discussion-between-art06-and-ivbtar).

Answer (score 0):

> How can i force this field to be editable ?

Instead of setting auto_now_add, you may override the save() method of the model, say

```
class AssistantNotes(BaseModel):
    ....
    notedate = models.DateField(db_index=True, verbose_name=_("Date"))
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.notedate = timezone.now()
        return super(AssistantNotes, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do we do this in models.py ?

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: Will the timezone updated everytime ? Because i tried similar solution by setting model field default value to timezone.now() and it didnt update the time although server time changed. It only updated it when i restart django once everyday.